# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _BuildScript_

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to load gradle project into eclipse oxygen which works very well before i install groovy on my machine. The only thing i suspect was groovy installation but i also removed those from environment vars.

Eclipse: Oxygen
Windows 10: 64bit
Gradle - 4.3

we have this as first lline

```
  apply from: "${commonscripts}/common.gradle"
```

in the gradle file on every module.

now suddenly i am getting below stack trace

```
         Loading Gradle project preview failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
         Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle installation 'K:\Softwares\gradle-4.3'.

         A problem occurred configuring root project 'project-module-core'.
         Could not create an instance of type build_5jow5481qoxwx49by9ooo1sk8.
         _BuildScript_
         org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle installation 'K:\Softwares\gradle-4.3'.
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:50)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invokeRun(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:170)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invoke(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:160)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.get(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$2.get(DefaultModelProvider.java:122)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$3.call(DefaultModelProvider.java:142)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
            at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:153)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:138)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeModelBuilder(DefaultModelProvider.java:118)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModel(DefaultModelProvider.java:69)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchGradleBuild(DefaultModelProvider.java:93)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.fetchGradleBuildStructure(ProjectPreviewJob.java:86)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.runToolingApiJobInWorkspace(ProjectPreviewJob.java:75)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob$1.run(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:79)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
            at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:76)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
         Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'tp-driver-rba2'.
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
            at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
            at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:137)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
            at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
            at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
            at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
            at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
            at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:55)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
            at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
            at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
            at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
         Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'tp-driver-rba2'.
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:66)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:656)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:135)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
            at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:249)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:167)
            at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
            ... 62 more
         Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type build_5jow5481qoxwx49by9ooo1sk8.
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:55)
            at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.getScript(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:55)
            at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:85)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:209)
            at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
            at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:214)
            at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
            at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
            at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
            at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
            ... 81 more
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _BuildScript_
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator$ConstructorCache.create(DirectInstantiator.java:80)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator$ConstructorCache.create(DirectInstantiator.java:75)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ReflectionCache$WeaklyClassReferencingCache.get(ReflectionCache.java:56)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ReflectionCache.get(ReflectionCache.java:36)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:49)
            ... 96 more
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _BuildScript_
            at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler$ScriptClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:399)
            ... 101 more
```

I spent almost full day on this ..... 
I also replaced eclipse with new one, thought eclipe might be corrupted.
Updated Gradle to latest 4.3
 but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is due to version conflict with groovy installtion other than Gradle installation i have . I uninstalled groovy and removed reference in env vars.
All working fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have run into Groovy-Eclipse issue #370 (https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/370).  If you switch Groovy compiler level to 2.4 or below, this should not occur.

Window > Preferences > Groovy > Compiler > Groovy Compiler settings section

Comment: Just wanted to make a quick update.  The gradle process was failing because the property "indy" compilation mode was being set for groovy.  Groovy-Eclipse no longer does this through system properties, so this issue should not be seen for Groovy 2.5+ in Eclipse any more.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue by changing the Gradle version to the latest one within the **project -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties** file.  Changing the value of the **distributionUrl** key to point to a newer version of Gradle - e.g. - **https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip** - causes the system to download the latest binaries and all internal settings are reconfigured (in some way I guess).

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the same issue today in Eclipse Photon (4.8) and then in SimRel 4.9. None of the solutions posted here helped (perhaps because I have the BuildShip plugin installed), but what worked is described in https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/370#issuecomment-384886233 :

1) Uninstall groovy plugins in eclipse
2) Kill gradle daemon processes
3) Rename or delete the "scripts" and "scripts-remapped" folders in the gradle cache (I ended up having to delete pretty much all the contents of the .gradle\caches folder)